# Is it true that the English have many words for hill?

Tags: british-english

I've heard it said that Eskimos have many words for snow and that the English have many words for hill.  If so what are they?

Comment: Related (not a dupe): [Do the Eskimo/Inuit languages really have more words for snow than English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/)

Comment: This may also be a reference to tautological duplication in many English place names constructed from multiple languages, such as [Pendle Hill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendle_Hill#History) (hill hill hill), and the anecdotal but [apparently incorrect Torpenhow hill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torpenhow_Hill) (which is alleged to mean hill hill hill hill, but probably doesn't).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An excerpt from *Key Concepts in Language and Linguistics* by *R.L. Trask*:

> Those Eskimo words for 'snow'. By a
>   comical series of events, the legend
>   has grown up that the Eskimo languages
>   have vast numbers of words for
>   different kinds of snow. In fact, the
>   several dialects of the two Eskimo
>   languages variously exhibit between
>   two and four distinct words for snow.
>   This is about the same as English with
>   its *snow*, *slush*, *sleet*, *blizzard* (not
>   to mention skiers' terms like
>   *hardpack*, *powder* and *crust*).

After a quick search, I hit the following words related snow in Alaskan/Eskimo/Inuit languages:

> **Akkituyok**: soft snow
>   **Aput**: snow used for a specific purpose
>   **Aquutaq**: snow
>   **Mangokpok**: watery snow
>   **Massak**: soft snow
>   **Massalerauvok**: snow filled with water
>   **Mauja**: soft deep snow
>   **Pukak**: snow crust
>   **Qaniit**: falling snow
>   **Qannik**: snowflake
>   **Sesi**: snow
>   **Tipvigut**: snowdrift

Regarding the English words for **hill**, the following are its synonyms:

> brae (Scot.)
>   down (archaic)
>   elevation
>   eminence
>   fell
>   height
>   hillock
>   hummock
>   knoll
>   mound
>   mount
>   prominence
>   tor

Also see this page for a list of ["hill" synonyms and "hill" related words](http://www.synonyms.ca/hill-synonyms.htm).

Comment: +1 for quoting Trask's book. I was vaguely reminded of that too when reading the question (or well, a very similar passage in his other book *Language: The Basics*).

Comment: Also "dune" from which "down" originated. The Old English word was *dun*, pronounced "dune".

Comment: _down_ is not archaic.  I used to live on the South Downs.  They stretch from the white cliffs of Dover to Winchester.

Comment: @ukayer - I think it (and several of the others) are archaic in general usage - they would no longer be used to mean hill but they would be used to refer to specific hills.

Comment: @neil - maybe, but archaic is bit strong.  I could go for "down" being used to describe a type of chalk escarpment found in Southern England.  In any case, in that area the hills are called "downs" either The North Downs (nearer London) or the South Downs which run along the coast and give rise to the white cliffs of Dover.  It is the term commonly used for the hills in that part of the country.

Comment: @ukayer - OK, I guess I'm too distant (Scotland) to know the usage in the souh of England.  Certainly here it would only be used to refer to those specific ones.